# Can elasticsearch client version 8.X communicate with elasticsearch server version 7

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7, spring-boot-3, elasticsearch-8

I have 2 questions:
1: can elasticsearch client version 8 communicate with elasticsearch server version 7?
2: how to configure spring data elasticsearch version 5

first of all, can client elasticsearch version 8 communicate with elasticsearch server version 7? second, in my spring boot application version 3 i'm trying to configure spring data elasticsearch version 5
so i added the dependendy in pom.xml,
then create my  configuration class: ClientConfiguration  like the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.restclient), but i don't found how to configure apiKey and index.name-suffix in application.yml .
i already did this config:

```
spring:
  elasticsearch:
    uris: localhost:9200
    socket-timeout: 1000
    connection-timeout: 1000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see how to configure Spring Data Elasticsearch and especially the client, check the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients).

The properties you are referring to are not from Spring Data Elasticsearch but from Spring Boot. To see which properties exist check the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.data). I don't know which of these properties Spring Boot uses to configure Spring Data Elasticsearch and which they use for configuring a standalone Elasticsearch client.

As for accessing an old cluster in version 7, you might try and set the compatibility headers (see the[the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.configuration.headers), but as far as I know this does not guarantee full compatibility. I remember from the migration phase to the new client and version 8, that even though these headers were set, the client in version 8 was not always sending the correct values or able to parse the version 7 answers.